# How to retrieve the thumbnail image of UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, tableview

I am displaying multiple images in a UITableViewCell like an thumbnail images. But i am struggling to retrieve the image of selected UITableViewCell. I have to do this for display the image in another ViewController. I am really struggling to  fix this issue.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if (cell==nil)
    {
         cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CellIdentifier"];

    }

   jsonDict = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSLog(@"imagess%@",jsonDict);
    cell.textLabel.text = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageName"];

    stringg=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.textLabel.text];

    cell.textLabel.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;


      NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];

      imageView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
     }
    return cell;

}



-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@",cell);

    NSString *textname=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cell.textLabel.text];
    NSLog(@"%@",textname);
 UIImage *image1 =selectedCell.imageView.image;
        age.ageimgae=image1;
}
```

Comment: have u show the screen shot of the page and code for image in cellforatindexpath and didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: check it now... @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: have u show the screen shot of the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` u need to identify the particular `Indexpath`

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{
jsonDict = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

 NSLog(@"the textr Name==%@",[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageName"]);

  UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]]];


NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image1);
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:imageData forKey:@"imageDataKey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]synchronize];
NSLog (@"Data Saved");


 }
```

here your choice u pass the NSData or your image to another view controller  using `NSUSerdefault` or `singleton` or `SharedInstance`, something else..

in secondviewcontroler.m

```
  nsdata *imagedata=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey@"imageDataKey"];

  yourimgaename.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString: imagedata]];
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of fetching the image of the selected cell, you can use the index of the selected cell in order to fetch the required image in your `JSonArray`(just like you did in  in your `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:`):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  
{
    jsonDict = [jsonArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"ImageData"]];
    UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
}
```